# cbind dataframes with different nrows by Date

Tags: r, date, join, cbind

I want to combine dataframes containing dates that are stored in a list. The first dataframe in the list represents the complete observation period, the subs are dates of different kind of observations.

```
start_date <- as.Date("2017/01/01")
original = as.data.frame (seq(start_date, by = "day", length.out = 365))

set.seed(5)
sub1 = original[-sample(1:365, 100, replace=FALSE),]
set.seed(4)
sub2 = original[-sample(1:365, 30, replace=FALSE),]

list(original, sub1, sub2.....)
```

I want to create one single dataframe that actually cbinds the whole list. Missing dates from the subs should be NA.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work.

```
colnames(original) <- "date"

head(cbind(original,
           sub1 = ifelse(original[,1] %in% sub1, as.character(original[,1]), NA),
           sub2 = ifelse(original[,1] %in% sub2, as.character(original[,1]), NA)),
10)
         date       sub1       sub2
1  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 2017-01-01
2  2017-01-02 2017-01-02 2017-01-02
3  2017-01-03       <NA> 2017-01-03
4  2017-01-04       <NA> 2017-01-04
5  2017-01-05 2017-01-05 2017-01-05
6  2017-01-06 2017-01-06 2017-01-06
7  2017-01-07 2017-01-07 2017-01-07
8  2017-01-08       <NA> 2017-01-08
9  2017-01-09       <NA> 2017-01-09
10 2017-01-10 2017-01-10 2017-01-10
```